# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str' for ID3

Tags: python, typeerror, decision-tree

I am currently trying to create a decision tree using the ID3 algorithm in Python. My code works with a simple dataframe of five categorical variables, but when I try to use it on a more complex dataframe I am getting

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

My dataframe contains 8 variables: brand (string), body (string), mileage (int), engine size (float), fuel type (string), registration (yes or no), year (int), model (string), and price (string, cheap or expensive). After the seventh feature is found I get the error.

Code:

```
features = [feat for feat in df]
features.remove("PriceC")

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
        self.value = ""
        self.isLeaf = False
        self.pred = ""

def entropy(examples):
    pos = 0.0
    neg = 0.0
    for _, row in examples.iterrows():
        if row["PriceC"] == "Cheap":
            pos += 1
        else:
            neg += 1
    if pos == 0.0 or neg == 0.0:
        return 0.0
    else:
        p = pos / (pos + neg)
        n = neg / (pos + neg)
        return -(p * math.log(p, 2) + n * math.log(n, 2))

def info_gain(examples, attr):
    uniq = np.unique(examples[attr])
    #print ("\n",uniq)
    gain = entropy(examples)
    #print ("\n",gain)
    for u in uniq:
        subdata = examples[examples[attr] == u]
        #print ("\n",subdata)
        sub_e = entropy(subdata)
        gain -= (float(len(subdata)) / float(len(examples))) * sub_e
        #print ("\n",gain)
    return gain

def ID3(examples, attrs):
    root = Node()

    max_gain = 0
    max_feat = ""
    for feature in attrs:
        #print ("\n",examples)
        gain = info_gain(examples, feature)
        if gain > max_gain:
            max_gain = gain
            max_feat = feature
    root.value = max_feat
    print ("\nMax feature attr",max_feat, " With Information Gain of", max_gain)
    uniq = np.unique(examples[max_feat])
    #print ("\n",uniq)
    for u in uniq:
        #print ("\n",u)
        subdata = examples[examples[max_feat] == u]
        #print ("\n",subdata)
        if entropy(subdata) == 0.0:
            newNode = Node()
            newNode.isLeaf = True
            newNode.value = u
            newNode.pred = np.unique(subdata["PriceC"])
            root.children.append(newNode)
        else:
            dummyNode = Node()
            dummyNode.value = u
            new_attrs = attrs.copy()
            new_attrs.remove(max_feat)
            child = ID3(subdata, new_attrs)
            dummyNode.children.append(child)
            root.children.append(dummyNode)

    return root

def printTree(root: Node, depth=0):
    for i in range(depth):
        print("\t", end="")
    print(root.value, end="")
    if root.isLeaf:
        print(" -> ", root.pred)
    print()
    for child in root.children:
        printTree(child, depth + 1)

def classify(root: Node, new):
    for child in root.children:
        if child.value == new[root.value]:
            if child.isLeaf:
                print ("Predicted Label for new example", new," is:", child.pred)
                exit
            else:
                classify (child.children[0], new)

root = ID3(df, features)
```

I have tried changing the datatypes of the variables, but I am not sure what the problem is. The error occurs after the seventh max feature attribute is found.

```
Max feature attr Registration  With Information Gain of 0.9182958340544896

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\python\Dir\venv\ExploreDataPortProjCSC425.py", line 135, in <module>
    root = ID3(df, features)
  File "M:\python\Dir\venv\ExploreDataPortProjCSC425.py", line 110, in ID3
    child = ID3(subdata, new_attrs)
  File "M:\python\Dir\venv\ExploreDataPortProjCSC425.py", line 103, in ID3
    newNode.pred = np.unique(subdata["PriceC"])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in unique
  File "M:\python\Dir\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 274, in unique
    ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts,
  File "M:\python\Dir\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 336, in _unique1d
    ar.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. There's no use of `<` in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You assert that price takes on one of two `str` values:
`"cheap"` or `"expensive"`.

Yet the `subdata.PriceC` column sometimes takes on `float` values.
And we cannot evaluate e.g. `1.0 < "cheap"`.
Examine the `.dtypes` and cast to new datatype as necessary.
Notice that "missing" (`None`) values will sometimes
introduce floating-point `NaN` values,
so consider making `.dropna()` part of your data cleaning pipeline.